# File Inout Output multiple delimiters

Tags: python

i am trying to construct a dictionary based on a file that is seperated by different delimiters. For example i the file im reading is structured the following way, i need the line as a variable for demonstrative purposes

```
g = "ENGL 1301,preprofessional,MATH 2413,"
if ","and "," in g :
    print "yay"
if "," and "," and "," in g:
    print "nay"
```

the file can have multiple commas which means different things so im trying to diffinterate between the amount of commas in the line. I want the above program to only print "nay" since there are 3 commas in the string and not 2. How can i accomplish this since the above program failed and printed both "yay" and "nay"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.count`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.count):

```
g = "ENGL 1301,preprofessional,MATH 2413,"
commas = g.count(",")  # I put this up here so it isn't called multiple times
if commas == 2:
    print "yay"
elif commas == 3:  # I used `elif` here since `commas` cannot equal 2 and 3
    print "nay"
```

---

Also, your current code doesn't work because non-empty strings evaluate to `True` in Python.  So, this:

```
if "," and "," in g :
    print "yay"
if "," and "," and "," in g:
    print "nay"
```

becomes like this:

```
if True and ("," in g):
    print "yay"
if True and True and ("," in g):
    print "nay"
```

As you can guess, each of those if-statements will *always* pass.

Comment: neat little tool. Thanks